# F#: How to create a Deedle Frame with SQL data source

Tags: sql, f#, deedle

I am trying to figure what is the best way in F# to create a Deedle Frame, when the data comes from an SQL server. I have tried things like the following.

```ml
#I "../packages/Deedle.0.9.12"
#load "Deedle.fsx"

#r "System.dll"
#r "System.Data.dll"
#r "System.Data.Linq"
#r "FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll"

open System
open System.Data
open System.Data.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open Deedle

type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=server;Initial     Catalog=database;Integrated Security=SSPI;">
let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()

let fr = db.SomeTable |> Frame.ofRows
```

and a few other variants. But without luck. I am new to both F# and Deedle for that matter.
I can see why the above does not work (the Frame.ofRows is not compatible with the argument) but I don't know what is the best way to proceed (or even how to proceed).

Comment: For the basic users here it's helpful to point out to *see* the results
shown at "The result is:" you need to call the Frame.Print() so for the above example fr.Print()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Frame.ofRows` function expects a sequence of series that represent individual rows of the frame. Similarly to `Frame.ofColumns`, this function is useful if you already have some series objects (or if you are creating everything from scratch). They take input of type `seq<'TRowKey * ISeries<'TColKey>>`.

When you're creating Deedle frame from some .NET data structure, you can use `Frame.ofRecords` which will work on any sequence and it will use reflection to get the names of the properties (and treat them as column names).

A long explanation, but just a few characters change in your code :-). I tested it with Northwind:

```ml
type Nwind = SqlDataConnection<"""Data Source=.\SQLExpress;
  Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;""">
let db = Nwind.GetDataContext()

// Create data frame from Products table (with appropriate column names)
let fr = db.Products |> Frame.ofRecords
```

The result is:

```
      ProductID ProductName                      SupplierID CategoryID QuantityPerUnit     UnitPrice UnitsInStock UnitsOnOrder ReorderLevel Discontinued OrderDetails                               Categories Suppliers 
0  -> 1         Chai                             1          1          10 boxes x 20 bags  18.0000   39           0            10           False        System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1[OrderDetails] Categories Suppliers 
1  -> 2         Chang                            1          1          24 - 12 oz bottles  19.0000   17           40           25           False        System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1[OrderDetails] Categories Suppliers 
2  -> 3         Aniseed Syrup                    1          2          12 - 550 ml bottles 10.0000   13           70           25           False        System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1[OrderDetails] Categories Suppliers 
3  -> 4         Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning     2          2          48 - 6 oz jars      22.0000   53           0            0            False        System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1[OrderDetails] Categories Suppliers 
4  -> 5         Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix           2          2          36 boxes            21.3500   0            0            0            True         System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1[OrderDetails] Categories Suppliers 
(....)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. Saw the method, but thought it only applied to records defined "the usual way". What is the best way to key the frame, if I want say  two columns to define the key. A day, and an hour?